# Count instanceses of a field in another table

Tags: sql-server, count

I have 2 Tables.

Table.Workorders with column.LinkID, Table.OptimizationResults with column.LinkIDWorkorder

I need to get a Table that has column.LinkID and Count (being how many rows the LinkID matches Table.OptimizationResults's column.LinkIDWorkorder.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
  dbo.Workorders.LinkID,
  COUNT(dbo.OptimizationResults.LinkIDWorkOrder) AS TotalCount
FROM
  dbo.Workorders
  LEFT JOIN
    dbo.OptimizationResults
  ON
    dbo.OptimizationResults.LinkIDWorkOrder = dbo.Workorders.LinkID
GROUP BY
  dbo.Workorders.LinkID
ORDER BY TotalCount DESC
```

It doesn't error out, but I get 0 in every result. Even thou I have confirmed they exist.

Comment: Can you provide de DDL of the table and some sample data to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure data exists? When I create 2 tables as you describe and run your query, I get the expected results.

```
USE Test;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Workorders;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OptimizationResults;

CREATE TABLE Workorders
(
    LinkID INT
);
GO

CREATE TABLE OptimizationResults
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    LinkIDWorkOrder INT
);
GO

INSERT INTO Workorders
VALUES
(1  ),
(2),
(3),
(4);

INSERT INTO OptimizationResults
VALUES
(1  ),
(1),
(3),
(4);


SELECT wo.LinkID,
       COUNT(omr.LinkIDWorkOrder) AS TotalCount
FROM dbo.Workorders AS wo
    LEFT JOIN dbo.OptimizationResults AS omr
        ON omr.LinkIDWorkOrder = wo.LinkID
GROUP BY wo.LinkID
ORDER BY TotalCount DESC;
```

Comment: 100% sure. I even tried hardcoding a value that I know exists and I get the correct result. If I use the field value I am getting just 0's.

Also not sure if it matters but the data is not a number. Eg. Real data:

`221FHJRURJTE
221FK94FMU3E
221FN1MTYURE
221FODDV3LHE
221KIRKAKVUE
221PPAXLJFIE
2227L9L20L4E
222EGQUDRLLE
222IGO8F74XE
222LKFZKNF0E
222LL52NM2AE
222NKMKJOTBE
222OM1UFGJUE
2234OCBXJ7QE
2235HQ7EFQSE
2237LKIVQ5VE
2238MLX1WD9E
2239L4YEINBE
223AL9VOOP6E
223FH6MJMNAE
223FQ7YQKOOE
223JIKXYA3LE
223ML7987JEE
223QP5ZIUHME
223TI29PNXBE
221FHJRURJTE
221FK94FMU3E`

Comment: Can you provide insert scripts.

Comment: And what version is your compat level of the database

Comment: Not overly familiar with how to get the INSERT script easily. I am trying to read and display data from an existing MSSQL database running on SQL 2019 from a proprietary application. So I can't change the database at all. I am trying to read the data and then later save modified data into a MySQL database in which I am familiar.

Comment: I think I got the INSERTS.

Download the 2 tables here (including first 100 records of real data)

https://www.eangulus.net/OptimizationResults.sql
https://www.eangulus.net/Workorders.sql

And for clarification, I am working with the Workorders table mainly. I need to get the workorders LinkID and count how many matches it has matched to the OptimizationResults->LinkIDWorkorder.

Comment: the given data does not have corresponding Workorders -> LinkIDWorkorders.
Which one should be known in both tables?

Comment: Everything in your OptimizationResults has a LinkIDWorkorder of '21B5HGAG5OOE'. This one is not known in the WorkOrders

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140861/discussion-between-peter-and-shaun-williams).

Comment: OK, I am showing a List of the Workorders Table, LinkID, Name and Status.

I then need to take Workorders->LinkID and count how many times it shows in the OptimizationResults->LinkIDWorders and show as another column (Total)

Comment: Tweak the values to make it work. I promise there is 100% without a doubt records that do match. The tables both contain over 500,000 rows, I only dumped the first 100 records of each.